# Exponentiation and logarithm with rational input and output

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, exponentiation, computability, computational-mathematics

Does an algorithm $f : ℚ^+ × ℚ \to ℚ^?$ such that:

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \text{Just} \space x^y & \quad \text{if} \quad x^y \in ℚ \\
            \text{Nothing} & \quad \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
exist? If so, how is such algorithm implemented?

Also, is there an analogous algorithm for $\log_xy$ (Provided that $x≠1$)?

Answer (score 1):

by necessary conditions, if $y$ doesn't have a denominator $d$ that both numerator and denominator of $x$ are perfect $d$-th powers game over.

Similarly for log to get integers the property is needed for both numerator and denominator of $y$ must be perfect powers of  the respective part of $x$ unless they would simplify due to common factors.  for all rational parts there must exist a rational exponent you can use to get $x$ to that part.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented your method of exponentiation by Newton method. But I'm still unsure that I can do logarithm, for example, $\log_4{2} = ½$. Could you explicitly demonstrate your algorithm to this example?

Comment: I'm just listing necessary conditions. You asked how ir was implemented, not what are steps, first step though is noting necessary conditions.